# Form Post doens't work on Iphone

Tags: javascript, php, html, iphone

Hi there I have a problem with form with method post. When I try execute this form on the computer it goes well, in Android too, but with Iphone I get an error on nginx error.log saying that method is not a POST. Here is the form:

```
<form name="info_form" id="info_form" action="add_voucher.php" method="post">   
<input type="hidden" name="mac" value="<?php echo $data['mac']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="ip" value="<?php echo $data['ip']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="link-login" value="<?php echo $data['linklogin']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="link-orig" value="<?php echo $data['linkorig']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="chap-id" value="<?php echo $data['chapid']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="chap-challenge" value="<?php echo $data['chapchallenge']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="link-login-only" value="<?php echo $data['linkloginonly']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="link-orig-esc" value="<?php echo $data['linkorigesc']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="mac-esc" value="<?php echo $data['macesc']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="dst" value="<?php echo $data['dst']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="error" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $data['username']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="popup" value="true" />
<input type="hidden" name="password" value="<?php echo $data['password']; ?>"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="enable-email-auth" value="<?php echo $data['enable_email_auth']; ?>" />  
<input type="hidden" name="link-redirect" value="<?php echo $data['linkredirect']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="facebook-login" id="facebook-login" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="facebook-email" id="facebook-email" value="<?php echo $me['email']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="icon-file-name" value="<?php echo $data['icon_file_name'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="background-file-name" value="<?php echo $data['background_file_name'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="facebook-id" id="facebook-id" value="<?php echo $me['id'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="google-id" id="google-id" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="google-email" id="google-email" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="realm-name" value="<?php echo $data['realmname'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="realm-id" value="<?php echo $data['realmid'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="user-id" value="<?php echo $data['userid'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="profile-mac" value="<?php echo $data['profile-mac'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="profile-social" value="<?php echo $data['profile-social'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="days-valid-mac" value="<?php echo $data['days-valid-mac'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="hours-valid-mac" value="<?php echo $data['hours-valid-mac'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="minutes-valid-mac" value="<?php echo $data['minutes-valid-mac'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="days-valid-social" value="<?php echo $data['days-valid-social'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="hours-valid-social" value="<?php echo $data['hours-valid-social'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="minutes-valid-social" value="<?php echo $data['minutes-valid-social'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="page-lang" value="pt">
<input type="hidden" name="enable_premium_login" value="<?php echo $data['enable_premium_login'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="gender" value="<?php echo $me['gender']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="age" value="<?php echo $age; ?>">
```

And here is the javascript that submit the form:

```
document.info_form.submit();
```

In the error.log file what i get is:

> [error] 1901#0: *1425 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: *******
>   Nao e um POST, add_voucher.php *******!" while reading response header
>   from upstream, client: 10.20.30.7, server: _, request: "GET
>   /login/add_voucher.php HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock:",

Comment: Your form isn't closed. Also you shouldn't be using the document object like that. `document.getElementById("info_form").submit();` is what you should use.

Comment: When I copied the form I forgot to copy the close of the form. I tried the document.getElementById("info_form").submit(); but same error occurs in the Iphone always send the form with get instead of post.